# How to find value from dictionary

Tags: swift, filter, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have following simple dictionary and I want latitude array when status 1 it is store one array and status 2 it store second array 
Please help me out

```
 data =     (
            {
        created = "2017-11-13 09:04:18";
        "end_date" = "2017-11-13 11:49:08";
        id = 878;
        latitude = "23.032190322875977000";
        longitude = "72.565238952636720000";
        status = 1;
        "user_id" = 21;
    },
            {
        created = "2017-11-13 11:49:08";
        "end_date" = "2017-11-13 13:13:15";
        id = 888;
        latitude = "23.032133102416992000";
        longitude = "72.565208435058600000";
        status = 1;
        "user_id" = 21;
    },
            {
        created = "2017-11-13 13:13:15";
        "end_date" = "2017-11-13 13:26:26";
        id = 891;
        latitude = "23.032199859619140000";
        longitude = "72.565269470214840000";
        status = 2;
        "user_id" = 21;
    },
            {
        created = "2017-11-13 13:26:26";
        "end_date" = "2017-11-13 16:54:20";
        id = 892;
        latitude = "23.032056808471680000";
        longitude = "72.565223693847660000";
        status = 2;
        "user_id" = 21;
    }
```

)

Comment: You can use NSPredicate

Comment: it is not woking

Comment: i also use for loop

Comment: let status = (dictionary.value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! NSArray
                                     print(status)
                                   
                                    for i in status
                                    {
                                        print(i)
                                        if i == 1
                                        {
                                             print("simple array")
                                        }

                                    }

Comment: it is not working

Comment: Edit your question and add code, don't post code in comments.

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` and `map` for this:

```
let statusOne = data.filter({ $0.status == 1 }).map({ $0.latitude })
let statusTwo = data.filter({ $0.status == 2 }).map({ $0.latitude })
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please try below code: its in swift 3:**

```
    let lattitude1Array = NSMutableArray()
    let lattitude2Array = NSMutableArray()
    for record in data {
        if let status = record["status"] as? Int {
            if status == 1 {
                lattitude1Array.add(record["lattitude"])
            } else {
                lattitude2Array.add(record["lattitude"])
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you be using NSMutableArray in Swift? Why not just an Array? Have you looked at the Array functions for filtering?

Comment: @gnasher729 I want mutable array. So i used NSmutableArray. If you want you can used Array.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code use this

```
func storeLatitudeAndLongnitude()
{
    let yourArray = NSArray()
    var arr_latitude_1 = [String]()
    var arr_latitude_2 = [String]()

    for item in yourArray
    {
        let dictData = item as! NSDictionary
        let status = dictData["status"] as? Int ?? 1
        let latitude = dictData["latitude"] as? String ?? "default_value"

        if status == 1
        {
            arr_latitude_1.append(latitude)
        }else
        {//For 2
            arr_latitude_2.append(latitude)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but only you need do if let binding instead of forcefully unwarpping. Please update your answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below lines of codes

```
    var firstArray = NSMutableArray()
    var secondArray = NSMutableArray()

    for i in 0 ..< data.count{
        if (data.object(at: i) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as? Int != nil {
            if (data.object(at: i) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! Int == 1 {
                let dummyDict = data.object(at: i) as! NSMutableDictionary
                firstArray.add(dummyDict)
            } else if (data.object(at: i) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! Int == 2 {
                let dummyDict = data.object(at: i) as! NSMutableDictionary
                secondArray.add(dummyDict)
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope that will help you :)